# Image as planes not entirely transparent above procedural metallic shader

Tags: rendering, image, transparency

I want to add a decal to my model, which has a procedurally generated metallic car paint shader. To help myself with easy changing of the decals, i don't want to add decals as image textures and with UVs. Hovewer the result looks like the image is not entirely transparent. I am using cycles.

[image]

I have prepared decals, that are saved in PNG file.

My steps:

1. Made sure that the alpha in the background is completely equal to 0 (select whole background in GIMP, delete).
2. Import "Image as planes" - alpha set to 'straight'. Scaled and rotated, etc.
3. Added Subdivision (Lev 6) and Shrinkwrap
4. Added small offset to the Shrinkwrap
5. Node setup as follows
6. Tried changing offset value (even to 1mm) of shrinkwrap, settings of the shader (including setting IOR to 1) and light paths. Then reseted everything to default values and posted here.

It seams like the transparent layer of my decal is interacting somehow with the metallic shader underneath... Does anybody have any idea what is happening?

Thank you guys!

[image: Nodes]

PS. In viewport shading it looks perfect.

[image: Viewport shading]

PS2. Updated
[Link](https://we.tl/t-wJRQPMedL6)

Comment: Can you share a file?  This is potentially interesting.  Would need textures packed.

Comment: Yeah, I prepared a small file with everything that is important. Same problem occurs. It is at the bottom of my first post. @Nathan

Comment: Getting a "file format not supported" on your linked file.  What version?

Comment: Blender 3.0, installed a week ago or so

Comment: The uploaded file is 0 bytes. @Daniel14223

Comment: I updated the link. It opens normally when I download it on my second computer. @Benus

Comment: it also happens with other transparent images in other Blender versions, it looks like it has to do with the material of the plane underneath (Blue Car Paint), it would be interesting to understand what's the problem with this material

Comment: @moonboots That's exactly what I thought. However, I don't have neither knowledge nor experience to find out what is goint on :/

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the Car Paint nodegroup has issues with noise. I suppose giving more samples would help, but I'm not gonna spend time trying.

What you can do instead of using a mesh plane to add your logo, is to simply mix your logo texture into the carpaint shader:

[image]

Comment: Wow, thanks! It's a nice and clean solution